# Client side checking before mapping to resource/ url mapping

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I have created a API which is used to upload file on AWS S3.

I want to restrict the file size to 10MB.

The following is my API.

```
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response kafkaBulkProducer(InputStream a_fileInputStream) throws IOException {

// UPLOADING LOGIC

}
```

As much as I understand when a request is made to my API the data/InputStream is loaded on my server.
This is consuming resources (connection etc.).

Is there any way by which I can identity the file size before the URL is mapped or resource mapping is done, so that if my file size is greater than 10MB I will not allow it to reach my server.

I think I can work with pre-filter. But my biggest concern and question is when the API is called, will the stream data will be stored on my server first ?
Do the pre-matching filter will help, so the the data will not be stored on my server in case if its size is greater than 10MB.

Basically I don't want to store data on my server then check the size and then upload to s3.
I want a solution where I can check the file size before loading to server and then I can upload to S3.

This API I will be using with `curl`.

How can I do this.

I hope I am clear about my question.

Thank you